# Trying to run two PHP functions in one program, which are executed by a button click

Tags: php, html, file, function

Hi I'm trying to run two PHP functions from one program which are executed by pressing two html form inputs, A table with 2 buttons, Start and Remove; Start writes a file 'ON' and Remove writes a file 'OFF' but at the moment when i click both of the buttons in runs the php scripts with both out puts as OFF please Help!

---

The table with the buttons.

```
<html>
<TABLE BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="10">
<TD>
<table BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3">
           <TH>Socket 1</th>
           <TR></tr>
           <TD>Serial Number</TD> <TD>ON/OFF</TD>
           <TR></TR>
           <TD>Elapsed Time </TD> 
           <TD><?php
                 include_once ("statusfileon.php")         
                     ?></TD> 
           <TD><?php 
                 include_once ("statusfileoff.php")         
                     ?></td>
           <TR></TR>
           </TABLE>
</TD>
<TD>
<table BORDER="3" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3">
           <TH>Socket 2</th>
           <TR></tr>
           <TD>Serial Number</TD> <TD>ON/OFF</TD>
           <TR></TR>
           <TD>Elapsed Time</TD> <TD>Start</TD> <TD>Remove</td>
           <TR></TR>
           </TABLE> 
</TD>
</TABLE>
</html>
```

---

Satusfileon.php

```
<?php // statusfileon.php
      //Write file if button is clicked
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
               statusfileon();
}
?>
<?php //Write file function
function statusfileon(){ //File function name.
$fh = fopen("statusfile.txt", 'w') or die("Fail to create file");
//Text which is displayed in file (on).
$text = <<<_END
on
_END;
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to file"); // If file location could not be found file isn't writen.
fclose($fh); //Close file.
}
?>
<html>
   <!--Button and variable for file permission. -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start">
      </form>
</html>
```

---

statusfileoff.php

```
<?php // statusfileoff.php
      //Write file if button is clicked.
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
               statusfileoff();
}
?>
<?php //Write file function 
function statusfileoff(){ //File function name.
$fh = fopen("statusfile.txt", 'w') or die("Fail to create file");
//Text which is displayed in file (off).
$text = <<<_END
off 
_END;
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to file"); // If file location could not be found file isn't writen.
fclose($fh); //Close file.
}
?>
<html>
   <!--Button and variable for file permission. -->
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove">
      </form>
</html>
```

---

Any help would gladly be appreciated as I'm new to programming please excuse any bad practices
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <TD><?php
       include_once ("statusfileon.php")         
  ?></TD> 
       <TD><?php 
             include_once ("statusfileoff.php")         
  ?></td>
```

PHP is executed by the server **before** the HTML is served up. So it isn't like clicking the buttons is calling your PHP function.

In this case, `statusfileon()` is executed and right afterwards, `statusfileoff()` is executed and then the page is served to your browser. **Button clicks aren't doing anything.**

---

To execute the code, you might want to redirect the user to `statusfileon.php` or `statusfileoff.php` on click of the button using an HTML link if you want the behaviour you are looking for.